# Error en npm install vue-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

Hola amigos tengo un error cuando uso npm install vue-slect me dice que no tengo las version corerecta de vue la actualice y sigue saliendo no se que hacer.

```
PS C:\xamppIVR\htdocs\proyectoInsertia> npm install vue-select       
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree    
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.29
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   dev vue@"^3.2.29" from the root project     
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"2.x" from vue-select@3.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-select
npm ERR!   vue-select@"*" from the root project        
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Andres Felipe Garcia\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andres Felipe Garcia\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-04T22_25_53_536Z-debug.log
```

Que podria hacer en este caso?

Comment: probaste con ``npm install vue-select@beta``?

Comment: Te amo tenias razon :')

Comment: excelente, lo agregué en forma de respuesta con la fuente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que la versión del paquete que querés instalar espera encontrar Vue2 pero tu proyecto está en Vue3

Según esta discusión (https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/1251), la librería con soporte para Vue3 deberías instalarla con el siguiente comando

```
npm install vue-select@beta
```

o

```
yarn add vue-select@beta
```

> Entiendo que en algún momento deberían pasar esta versión `beta` a la versión final (vue-select, sin necesidad de @beta o @next), pero de momento, y desde hace casi dos años funciona así.